# Bearer O'Riley!

Tags: word, wordplay, knowledge

> My prefix is words you should not care.
>
> My suffix is the birth of the dragon chair.
>
> My infix is the exit from the angel lair.
>
> My whole is the result of what I bear.

**What am I?**

---

Hint:

> The dragon is red.

Hint 2:

> The result is considered a bad thing.

Hint 3:

> There's a red sun lie in between the red dragon and the angle lair.

Answer (score 2):

Closest I can get is

> **Conveyor**

Broken down this is

> **Con** - A swindle, involving words that should not be trusted or cared for
>
> **Vey** - Apparently yiddish for woe, falling from heaven would be pretty woeful
>
> **Or** - Gold, the treasure that dragon's like to sit on
>
> **Conveyor** - Something that bears or carries something

I did also experiment with

> **Gate** for heaven's exit, giving a suffix of -gator; or even **Gateau** using **au** for gold!

I'm really struggling with your first line, it doesn't really make sense in English and I'm finding it hard to interpret